# Use GLKit or Not?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I am in the midst of learning OpenGl ES for IOS.

Other than backward compatibility for stuff below IOS 5, what is anyones opinion of developing a 3D Graphics based game using straight up OpenGl ES 2.0 without the GLKit stuff?

I realize that the kit makes somethings easier. I'm not totally concerned about easier, just whether there is more capability using OpenGl ES 2.0 without the GLKit.